# preveting alt + numpad with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need prevent alt+numpad with javascript, because I want prevent some characters, but with this method, can write any character.

I try prevent keydown and dont work

```
$("#dialog-modal").on("keydown",".nombrePagina",function(e)
{
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just allowing what you need? You can run regex test, if invalid delete last character

Comment: I have a div, and a input text, when i write in the input text, the text appears in the div, i want prevent html code.
`code`$("#dialog-modal").on("keydown",".nombrePagina",function(e)  {   
   var ignore_key_codes = [60,191,111,62,104];
   var ignore_shift_key_codes = [55];
      if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, ignore_key_codes) >= 0){
         e.preventDefault();
      }
      if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, ignore_shift_key_codes) >= 0 && e.shiftKey ){
         e.preventDefault();
      }

   
  });
This work for me. But when i put alt+numpad i cant block this.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me!
Thanks!

```
 $('#t').keypress(function(e){
    var txt = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    console.log(txt + ' : ' + e.which);
    if(!txt.match(/[A-Za-z0-9+#.]/))//+#-.
    {
        return false;
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your question, including:

1. You can't prevent people from *typing* special characters, even if you block the alt key, what stops someone from coping and pasting it?
2. You can't control anything except your webpage (and sometimes webpages that you open) in Javascript (imagine going to a webpage that then destroys your entire computer! Scary!)

Why not use Regexp instead to block characters before it gets used?

Something like `/[:']+/` will work (explanation image below from [Regexper](http://regexper.com))

[image: Regex Explanation]

The `.replace` function on strings takes a Regex's matches, and replaces it with the 2nd argument.

```
var badString = "this ':' is awful"
badString.replace(/[:']+/, '') //=> 'this  is awful'
```

Be warned that if you are communicating with an API, someone could send their own request, bypassing the **client** side verification, so you might be best off using server-side verification, too.

Look at the documentation for Regex in your server's language:

- [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
- [Ruby/Rails](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub)
- [Python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)
- [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: #1 is irrelevant ... a class can be made up of any valid characters and nothing says it has to be in any specific language. There is no reasonable reason that OP should have to translate them either just to post  question

Comment: @charlietfl I thought there was. Fixed my answer :D